# (error )Trying to get property 'id' of non-object laravel8

Tags: html, laravel, authentication, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to store data by using id as primary key in Laravel 8, I used following code in controller :

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $job = new Job();
        $job->employeer_id = Auth()->user('employeer')->id;
      
        $job->category = $request->category_name;
        $job->job_context = $request->job_context;
        $job->keywords = $request->keywords;
        $job->title = $request->title;
        $job->vacancy = $request->vacancy;
        $job->deadline = $request->deadline;
        $job->employment_type = $request->employment_type;
        $job->location = $request->location;
        $job->gender = $request->gender;
        $job->age = $request->age;
        $job->responsibilities = $request->responsibilities;
        $job->education = $request->education;
        $job->requirements = $request->requirements;
        $job->additional_requirements = $request->additional_requirements;
        $job->salary = $request->salary;
        $job->benifits = $request->benifits;
        $job->apply_instruction = $request->apply_instruction;

        $job->save();
        Category::where('category_name', '=' , $request->category_name)->increment('no_jobs', 1);
        return redirect('/jobs');
    }
```

The error says that :
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
in this line :

````
        $job->employeer_id = Auth()->user('employeer')->id;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```php
Auth()->user('employeer')->id;
```

use

```php
Auth::guard('employeer')->id();
```

or

```php
auth('employeer')->user()->id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The first one give me the following error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$id.
while second one give me this one :SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'experience' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`employeer_id`, `category`, `job_context`, `keywords`, `title`, `vacancy`, `deadline`, `employment_type`, `location`, `gender`, `age`, `responsibilities`, `education`, `requirem

Comment: I update my code for the first error. I missed the braces.

Comment: On second error: you have a field **experience** in your table which is **not null**. You have to add **$job->experience = "something";** or you can simply make the field nullable.

Comment: still does not work

Comment: What is the last error you found?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get the user first

```
Auth::guard('employeer')->check();
```

Then put your code in condition if the user object exist.

So basically you should do this

```
if(Auth::guard('employeer')->check()){
    $job = new Job();
    $job->employeer_id = Auth::guard('employeer')->user()->id;

    // rest of the code
    
}else{
    // handle as you want 
}
```